# is there a android:onClick="abc", but for pressing and holding?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a single button in my app. (simplified) it looks like this:

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/SendButton"
        android:onClick="getCommand"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/circle_send" />
```

My java looks like this:

```
public void getCommand(View view)
{
    //my code here
}
```

My question is, is there an xml tag similar to android:onClick="abc", but that works for press+holds, separately from a tap? I want to have something like this:

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/SendButton"
        android:onClick="abc"
        android:onPressAndHold="xyz"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/circle_send" />
```

thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sorry. In general, we do not use XML attributes for event handlers. `android:onClick` is the only one built into Android, and it has been obsolete for years.

If you *really* want to do it, you could use data binding and create a `BindingAdapter` to give you support for an `app:onLongClick` attribute. However, the syntax of the binding expression that you would use with `app:onLongClick` would be more complicated than what you have for `android:onClick`.